# Drop-down menus in some Applications have visual problems

Tags: libreoffice

Example Pictures:

[image: Writer drop-down menu]
[image: Writer drop-down menu glitch after close menu]
[image: Other menu glitch example]

Have same problem in other apps like Gimp.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thx

Comment: Hi and welcome to elementary juno, how much ram does your computer have?

Comment: This computer have an intel non dedicated graphics card and 2Gb of Ram it’s an old HP Compaq dc7800p small factor. All schools of my country have dozens of them. Want to use elementary next school year but need to solve this first, cause I am loving Juno and don’t want a bug like this ruin all good things Juno have. Have 2Gb of swap on this machine too.

Comment: Happens too on Firefox bookmarks toolbar and almost all apps that have the top menu (sublime text, vscode, gimp, etc..). I think this glich is only in elemnentary juno.

Answer (score 0):

**@pbernardino**, the issue is probably a video glitch, but I doubt it's due to insufficient RAM or video memory, because I have experienced it on a very powerful machine with enough memory. So I guess this is what can be done about it:

1. Create a list of apps (in addition to LibreOffice and GIMP) where this drop-shadow glitch can be found, and update your post with it. This way it'll be easier to understand, what may cause the glitch (e. g., some specific library that these apps are using).
2. To make sure that the glitch is elementaryOS-specific (and, say, not Ubuntu-specific), it'd be great to test it on Ubuntu system. If it is present on Ubuntu too, then you can file a bugreport on [Ubuntu's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu). If it doesn't, try submitting a bugreport to elementary OS devs on a dedicated [github page](https://github.com/elementary).

Comment: Happens too in Audacity, Openboard and VLC. 
Doesnt happen in Chrome. 
If I have time and patient will try install Ubuntu later in other machine with same hardware. Or will forget ubuntu and sons and go to father Debian Buster.

Comment: Cant go for Debian cause this will be used by small children, so need to be an easy install, very updated and good looking distro to make a good image of LINUX.

Comment: Well, if you're in search of a reliable distro with frequent system updates and fixes, I guess this is a suitable case. Try reporting this drop-shadow video issue to the devs (Ubuntu and/or elementary OS) and see how fast you can get it fixed.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and no problem with menus.

Comment: Very interesting news! If this glitch isn't present on Ubuntu, I would definitely recommend to report this issue to elementary OS developers. Presumably, on a Gala Window Manager page:  https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues